# Unity BuildPipeline target Intel + Silicon on MacOs

Tags: macos, unity-game-engine, build, apple-silicon

Im trying to achive a unity build config in my code, my current version is `2021.3.25f1`

[Build settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZZlai.jpg)

```cs
  
public static class Builder
{

    public static string SdkPath = "/SDK/";
    
    [MenuItem("Build/mac", false, 0)]
    public static void BuildProject()
    {
        var scenes = new List<string>
        {
            "Assets/SinglePlayerCCGKit/Scenes/Menu.unity",
            "Assets/SinglePlayerCCGKit/Scenes/Game - UI Integration.unity",
            "Assets/SinglePlayerCCGKit/Scenes/Map.unity"
        };
        
        
        var options = new BuildPlayerOptions
        {
            scenes = scenes.ToArray(), 
            target =  BuildTarget.StandaloneOSX, 
            locationPathName = SdkPath + "into the grid.app",
        };
        
        BuildPipeline.BuildPlayer(options);
    
    }

}
```

I dont know what is the exact configuration to target the multi architecture build because in the enum `BuildTarget` is not available.

I search for a solution to this but the documentation is not clear enough